# make text size h2 responsive on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having problems making my custom `<h2>` class used on text responsive for mobiles

I want to make the this `h2` class resize to a text size of 49px when viewed on a mobile device.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    h2.josh {
       text-size:49px;}


h2.josh {

    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
     font-size: 79px;
color:white;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    opacity: 0.9;
 display:inline-block;
 display:inline-block}
 .dark-text{color: #1e1e1e}
 body { padding-top: 0px !important; }
```

Comment: You should consider setting the default first outside a media query, then specifying min width escalating from there. `h2.josh{ ... } @media screen and (min-width: 48em){ h2.josh{ ...next size after mobile... } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) { h2.josh { font-size:49px !important; } }
```

You're missing a bracket at the end. And try using !imporant with the style rule because maybe you have style rules applied within the element itself!

Comment: still displaying the orginal text size of 79px on mobile devices.

Comment: you're using text-size?? use font-size:49px !important

Comment: im sorry i ment  font size  i am using  font size and it still displaying it at 79px  rather than 49px

Comment: did you include !important ?

Comment: @media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
h2.josh {
   font-size:49px !important;
}
}

Comment: try using the revised media query!

Comment: only thing is it also make  the  text small on  desktops.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing curly bracket after the media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    h2.josh {
       text-size:49px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, do not use !important. Its not a good practice. And once you close the media query it should work. Also, keep using min-width rather than max-width. Modern development should be mobile-first and min-width is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

What is

```
text-size:49px; /*should be **font**-size*/
```

Also call this @media query after the other css not before or you will have to search whole document for the over ride. Always load these in last and you have put min-width? 
In this case you should be using max-width and use say 640px or 720 for the mobile devices etc. So everything less than eill take this style and as its being loaded last will take.